# Conditional Parameter based on User input in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement to call a parameter based on user input for another parameter. In short,

I have a parameter for build_type with choice values Daily, Release and Snapshot. Only whenever user selects Snapshot option for build_type, it should prompt user to enter snapshot name.

Do we have any plugin for this ?

Thanks,
Ras.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74875956
Its straight forward  you can also try this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin

**EDITED**
It does work, you just have to do a bit of groovy scripting  :)

First you need to select  Active Choice Parameter
[image]

Then select Active Choice Reactive reference Parameter

[image]

**Groovy script**

```
   if(States.equals("Snapshot")){
inputBox="<input name='Snapshot' type='text' >"
}
```

**TA-DA**
[image]

I'll leave the beautification/formatting to you :)

Comment: I tried that, there is no option for user entry.
It prompts the user with options defined inside the job, and it matches the defined parameters dynamically.
But, snapshots are not static and I could not assign them to any parameter. It must be user entry.

Comment: Thank you Rohit. Will give it a try today.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not test this due to a bug in configuration/plugin
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51719

Comment: @RasDama I think you need to add the whole stacktrace there ....plus this looks like a similar issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36361

Comment: Starting with Active Choices v2.0, sandboxed Groovy scripts for Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter will no longer emit HTML that is considered unsafe, such as <script> tags. This may result in behavior changes on Build With Parameters forms, such as missing elements. To resolve this issue, Groovy scripts emitting HTML will need to be configured to run outside the script security sandbox, possibly requiring separate administrator approval in In-Process Script Approval.

Comment: I see only radio buttons, single select, multi select and checkboxes options under choice type.

Comment: Do you have admin privileges ?? If you do, go to Manage Jenkins, Under that In-Process Script Approval  you need to approve this plugin features ...generally you will face these kinds of issue because it's not a widely used plugin and there might be security issue hence the added check...And don't except much support from the plugin as it's no longer available in Jenkins update center...If feasible, create your own plugin, will give you much better control and you wont have to worry about these issues :)

Comment: No pending classpath entry approvals. 



Classpath entries already approved:

No approved classpath entries.

Comment: Did you get the latest plugin for Active Choices Reactive ??

Comment: Hi Rohit, I have V2.1

Comment: I downloaded the same one ... and it's available there ....Did you select Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter or Active Choices Reactive Parameter because the former has `Formatted HTML` and the latter doesn't :)

Comment: Thank you so much Rohit. My bad, I have selected, Active Choices Reactive Parameter.
Now I have changed it to "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter", Looks good now.
Thank you so much.

Comment: No issues... happy to help :)

Comment: Could you please suggest the syntax for reading this HTML variable naming "Snapshot" in pipeline. Tried these, params.Snapshot, ${Snapshot}, $Snapshot 
but none of them is working. Kindly help.

Comment: @Tanul States is the variable and Snapshot is one of the values of States....

Comment: @rohit, in the image above can we get that zzzz value in pipeline. Is there anyway to read that textbox

Comment: @rohitthomas, hi, i'm also trying to fetch the user inputs (like "zzzz") to use it from groovy or shell step, but i can't get it. it's possible ??

Comment: try using inputBox `inputBox="<input name='Snapshot' type='text' >`

Comment: @rohitthomas, after i press build, i still can't find any argument as 'inputBox' or 'Snapshot' in the other Groovy/Shell Build Step. maybe you can see more details for my issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532153/how-to-get-user-inputs-from-jenkins-active-choice-parameter-using-formatted-html

Comment: @Tanul - hi, you was able to reach such "zzzz" value from user inputs ?

Comment: @AdirD, Any success getting the input value?

Comment: @guymi, yes :) follow this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62541190/6130501

Comment: @rohitthomas Can you please advise on how can I ignore `.env` (dotenv) file in jenkins, it would be really help  >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284867/how-can-i-ignore-the-actual-dotenv-env-file-while-running-in-jenkins