# How can I ignore the actual dotenv (.env) file while running in jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

In cypress how can I ignore the `dotenv` (.env) file while running in jenkins, as jenkins run on actual environment variables.  Now I am getting `No such file or directory` `open/student-proj/.env`
How can I check if it is running in jenkins then use actual env variables else use `.env`   ?

`plugins/index.js`

```
const configEnv = require('dotenv').config();
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());

  if (configEnv.error) {
    throw configEnv.error;
  }
  const env = { ...config.env, ...configEnv.parsed };
  
  const envData = { ...config, env };
  return envData;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

why not just use a jenkins env variable specific in your code e.g. JOB_NAME ... if the value returns null... that means its not running on jenkins

Comment: How can I check the jenkins ``env`` value is null ? Assume if  ``JENKINS_HOME`` is one of the jenkins variable. Can I do  `` if (JENKINS_HOME == null) {
  
  if (configEnv.error) {
    throw configEnv.error;
  }
  const env = { ...config.env, ...configEnv.parsed };
  
  const envData = { ...config, env };
  return envData;
  } else {
  
    // do nothing ...
  }``

Comment: But still the above will throw undefined ?

Comment: Yup JENKINS_HOME will have some value when running in Jenkins but will be null when you run it on your local machine....as  for the code I haven't worked on cypress